# Installing Python Modules for 3.X while 2.X is active in OS X

Tags: python, macos, pip, version, conflict

I'm trying to install some modules in Python 3.X and having issues.

Mac OS X comes with 2.X pre-installed. I've used pip to install various modules in 2.X so far.

The project that I'm working on conflicts in both environments. It keeps trying to run in the 2.X environment while I've been using 3.X practices (obviously is a problem).

I've tried uninstalling 2.X but can't stop it from being the default version. For instance, when I call python in bash, it goes to the 2.X version, and when I issue pip install  it attempts to install in 2.X.

I can run everything I need to from the 3.X IDLE, but I need to install modules to use for the project. I can't install them through pip or easy_install because that installs them in 2.X.

Thanks!

Comment: Use `pip3` and `python3` to refer to Python 3.X.

Comment: I feel like an idiot. Thanks!